# What does (0+) mean?

Tags: limits, probability-theory, laplace-transform

I'm currently learning from a script (which is written in German and not publicly available, sorry) for introduction to stochastics, where the topic is the Laplace transformed function for random variables where I found

$$E(X^k) = \lim_{s \downarrow 0} (-1)^k L_{X}^{(k)} (s) = (-1)^k L_{X}^{(k)} (0+)$$

What does the $(0+)$ mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(0^+)$ or less common $f(0+)$ refers to
$$\lim_{\epsilon\searrow 0} f(\epsilon) = \lim_{\epsilon\to0, \epsilon>0} f(\epsilon)$$
i.e. the right-sided limit of $f$ at $0$.